# remove key where value is false in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with a structure similar to the one shown.

```
var a = {};
a['key1'] = 'false';
a["key2'] = 'true';
a['key3'] = 'false';
a['key4'] = 'false';
a['key5'] = 'true';
```

I want to remove any entry with a value of false, resulting in an array as shown.

```
{key2:true, key5:true}
```

I can easily do this in php using array_filter, but I cant figure out the js equivalent. The nearest suggestion Ive found through searching is

```
for (var key in array) {
    if (array[key] == false) {
        array.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Read about `Array#filter`...

Comment: What language is this? (Associative arrays don't look—or work—like that in JavaScript, which it is tagged as)

Comment: That is an invalid javascript array. It could be an array, or a Javascript object. Can you update the post with the actual array you're trying to work with?

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are different to objects.  What you have there is an object, not an array.

Comment: ah so what you have is an object not an array really.

Comment: are the values strings or should they be boolean values?

Comment: change your values to boolean that code is bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the keys and delete the properties.

```js
var object = { key1: false, key2: true, key3: false, key4: false, key5: true };

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
    if (object[key] === false) {
        delete object[key];
    }
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: he says its an array? why do you consider that its an object?

Comment: in javascript there are no associative arrays, but objects.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd rather see the use of `=== false` to avoid ambiguity.  This will remove things that aren't strictly false.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array. Add just the ones you that fit your criteria:

```
                   var array = [true,false,true, true   ]

                    var newArray = [];

                    for(var key in array){
                        if(array[key] != false) 
                            newArray.push(array[key]) ; 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    for (var key in a) {
        if (a[key] == 'false') {
            delete a[key];
        }
    }
```